# Domain Driven Design and Automapper

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, automapper, solid-principles, ddd-repositories

I have a circular reference problem or a SOLID Violation in the following architecture:

```
 MVC / WebAPI (Presentation Layer)
     - ViewModels
     - Automapper

ApplicationServices
    - AppServices

Domain
     - Services
     - Models (Business Layer)

Infra.Data
     - Repositories
```

I need to perform the Mappings between the ViewModel and DTOs. However, I have a reference between MVC and Domain (That works fine). The Mapping should be done in the topmost layer, where it is the Presentation Layer. How to decouple it, make the mapping in Presentation Layer without reference the Domain?

If I Decouple the Automapper from Presentation Layer, I will have a circular reference because it needs the ViewModel, and the Presentation needs to call the mapping.

Comment: Why do you mention the Domain layer? What does it have to do with ViewModel<=>DTO mapping and decoupling mapping from Presentation?

Comment: We want to remove the reference of the Domain from the Presentation.

Comment: How is that in any way related to your mapping between Presentation layer and Application layer?

Answer (score 0):

It depends a bit on how you defined your interface. That will tell you where you need to do your mapping

When calling the next layer from the presentation layer your code would have to look like this

```
 ISomeService MyService;//Resolve this with your favorite dependency injection fromwork

 var result = MyService.MySeriviceCall(Automapper.Map<SomeEntity>(fooDto));
```

Notice here that the presentation layer depends on the interface (not implementation) of your service with everything that interface needs.

If your interface looks like this

```
 interface SomeService(SomeEntity foo)
```

THen you need to do your mapping in the presentation layer. But notice in order to call this service you already need to be aware of your domain layer since it's defined in your interface.

However, If your interface looks like this

```
interface SomeService(SomeDTo foo);
```

Then the reference is from your applicationService to both your domain model and presentation layer. And the mapping is done in the application service (my prefered place, and now you have Dependency Inversion). 
Note: you can put your DTO's in a separate project so you only need to be aware of those.

Also notice that defining your mapping and calling your mapping can de decoupled as well (https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Configuration)